# Edge throws "SCRIPT5007: Object expected"

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge-extension

This code is from background script and throws error in MS Edge (works fine in Chrome) when function is called:

```
const zoom = () => {
    console.log('zoom function');

    browser.tabs.getZoom(z =>  {
           //.......
    });
}
```

*zoom function* is written on console and then error is shown
**SCRIPT5007: Object expected**

I have **tabs** permission in manifest

Comment: It's not supported, even tho **tabs** API is  [listed under supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis)

Answer (score 0):

Tabs API class itself is supported on Edge. However, `tabs.getZoom` method is not yet supported. You can view compatibility details on this webpage :: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getZoom

You can however workaround this using JS in Content Script of your Extension. MS Edge provides this to measure zoom percentage.

```
screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI
```

You can view more details in this answer ::: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)